# Get date-time, date and time separately in logstash using grok

Tags: datetime, logstash-grok, grok

Input:

> 2018-11-28 10:22:29

Expected json output:

```
 {   
     "DateandTime": "2018-11-28 10:22:29",   
     "Date": "2018-11-28",  
     "Time": "10:22:29"
 }
```

Grok-pattern:
   ??

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an easy one and can be easily solved by means of basic grok-patterns. You can consult a reference to those grok-patterns [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/groklib/grok-patterns).

In this case I think that this pattern should solve your problem:

```
(?<DateandTime>(?<Date>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}) (?<Time>%{TIME}))
```

Maybe there is a more compact way of doing it using other grok-patterns but it should do the trick anyway.

Comment: Hi @Drubio, (?<Date>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}) why you have used this "?" <Date> for time we can use like %{TIME:time}

Comment: To be honest, this was over four years ago and I don't recall the syntax any longer. Sorry.